# To check a variable have no value or not in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <?php
 $username = $this->session->all_userdata();
 $myname = $username['logged_in']['filepath'];
 if ($myname === "") {
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/userpic/dummy.jpg"/>
 <?php
 } else {
 ?>
 <!---<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/userpic/$myname.jpg"/>--->
 <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/userpic/<?php echo $myname; ?>"/>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

I want to check that is the variable $myname has any value from the above code or not.How to check it that its empty.I have tested it with empty(),isset() function but its not working.Please help me with this.I want to upload adummy image if its empty

Comment: `tested it with empty(),isset() function but its not working` - can you explain?

Comment: i edited the code friend

Comment: `print_r($this->session->all_userdata())` and paste the result of it !!1

Answer (score 3):

> How to check that it's empty?

PHP has an [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

```
$myname = $username['logged_in']['filepath'];
if(empty($myname)) {
    // code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `!empty` which will check for both that variable `isset` and `not empty` as

```
if(!empty($myname)){
   <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/userpic/<?php echo $myname; ?>"/>
}else{
   <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/userpic/dummy.jpg"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of $myname you can also check on $username . this will be more suitable for you as you are assigning value from it to $myname.
use PHP empty() function like

```
if(!empty($username))
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: both the ways its not going in else section if i dont upload a image

Comment: Then you have any issue with your $username where you are assigning values to it . Please check $username['logged_in']['filepath'] value when yo are uploading .